# How to tell jetty maven plugin v9.1.x to *not* deploy dependent war artifacts?

Tags: java, jetty

I'm trying to start jetty at pre-integration-test phase.

```
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.1.3.v20140225:start (start-jetty) @ mainsite-tests ---
2014-03-18 01:07:31.878:INFO::main: Logging initialized @6944ms
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: MainSite Tests
[INFO] Webapp source directory = /devel/java/mainsite-tests/target/mainsite-distribution/apps
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes directory /devel/java/mainsite-tests/target/classes does not exist
[INFO] Configuring Jetty from xml configuration file = /devel/java/mainsite-tests/target/mainsite-distribution/conf/jetty.xml
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = /devel/java/mainsite-tests/target/tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] Dependent war artifact xyz:server:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Dependent war artifact xyz:ui:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Dependent war artifact xyz:tools-ui:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] web.xml file = null
[INFO] Webapp directory = /devel/java/mainsite-tests/target/mainsite-distribution/apps
2014-03-18 01:07:32.053:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.1.3.v20140225
```

The maven project uses the dependency maven plugin to unpack the mainsite-distribution zip, which is a combination of tanukisoft wrapper and the three WARs shown above in unpacked form. That zip file gets unpacked into target/mainsite-distribution.

Is there any jetty maven plugin configuration option to stop the plugin from pulling und unpacking the three wars separately, and instead only used the prepared environment below target/mainsite-distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I just told maven to ignore/remove all dependencies of mainsite-distribution.... beware however, that "partial wildcards" do not work (ie. "my.pkg.*").